# Best method of rolling out updates for a developed app not on the google play store

Tags: android, version-control, updates, google-play

Hello
Not sure if this is really the best place to ask but I was wondering if anyone has any good suggestions on rolling out updates for apps that have not been published on the google play store?
 I create apps to be used in house by other members of staff at my work place and there's either no need for the apps to be put on the play store or the apps that have been created are for private use only.
Currently i'm having to either email new versions of the apps to members of staff who then have to delete the old versions from their phones or I have to get hold of their phones and install the newer version from eclipse everytime I create a new version
 Obviously this is not ideal so I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions on how I could easily roll out updates to the phones with the apps installed??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic idea of auto-update is putting your new software somewhere your application know and can download from. Obviously you will need some sort of versioning in your application. Application should check for updates periodically, and if the online version is newer than current version it should download and update preferably by asking to the user if he/she wants to update.

Commonsguy has a library for this. It is a suspended project but it should give you the basic idea and you can even write your own library after that. [cwac-updater](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-updater) here you go.

Answer (score 0):

Make an update module in your application, that periodically polls a server to check for updates. Keep in mind that you have to do this in a battery-efficient way so as not to drain the battery of the user.

Another option could be using [GCM](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). Look it up. When you have an update, just send a message to all the devices to prompt the user to download the new version.